# Redis lock for specific key

Tags: java, spring, redis, service, spring-data-redis

I am using Redis for DB storage and 10 java microservices will be using it simultaneously.

For 1 of the key in Redis will be used by all 10 services. Is there any way to implement such that if 1 of the services is using that particular key in Redis then other services will be in hold state.

Comment: https://redis.io/commands/setnx/   setnx commands may helps you.

Answer (score 0):

so redis is not a transactional database which can assure the consistency or not even the eventual consistency ( in some use cases), so the solution to this problem might not be something that redis provides u already in my opinion. but then what I am assuming is that ur databases reads might have a common function file to call reads and write , u can lock a key before u want to read/write using another key pattern or a key_lock hash (KEY_LOCKS:'key')  and asynchronously disable the lock once ur read or write is finished to that key